# Is 0.1 bar (hydrostatic pressure) equivalent to 0.1 bar vacuum pressure (absolute pressure)?

Tags: pressure, terminology, fluid-statics

Suppose we would like to test the ability of an object to withstand the pressure under 1 meter of water.
I would like to understand how to simulate this situation using vacuum.

Is the 0.1 bar (for 1 m depth) pressure exerted on an object equivalent to 0.1 bar pressure (absolute pressure) inside the object?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I'd like to thank you for writing a very descriptive and helpful title. Most new users take time to get that right but you got it on your first post. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure of your level, so apologies if any of the following is telling you how to suck eggs.

When people say informally that there is a *vacuum* inside a vessel, they most often mean that the pressure exerted by the gas on the inside of the vessel is less than that exerted by the surrounding gas on the outside. The latter is most often the Earth's atmosphere at the time in question, *i.e.* a gas that exerts about $10^5{\rm N\,m^{-2}}$ on the outside.

Now, to understand how to simulate the stress induced on a vessel under certain conditions, *e.g.* steeping in water at a $1{\rm m}$ depth, with "vacuums" or, in general, with different conditions, the best approach is to draw a free body force diagram on a section of the wall of the vessel such as I have drawn below so you can understand exactly what is going on. You can understand from this diagram that the *stresses induced in the walls are a function only of the difference between the pressures inside and outside of the vessel*.

Therefore, to test whether the vessel can withstand submersion to $1{\rm m}$ depth, you must lower the pressure in the vessel's inside by one tenth of an atmosphere relative to the outside. That is, you're simply going to attach a vacuum pump and gauge and pump the vessel out until your vacuum gauge measures $0.1{\rm atm}$, or, more likely, this will be shown as $76{\rm mm\,Hg}$ (almost the same as to $76{\rm torr}$).

[image: Pressure Vessel]

Comment: If the vacuum gauge measure the absulute pressure, I would expect it to indicate 0.9atm which is 0.1 atm less pressure then external pressure which would be equivalent of submerging the object one meter deep in water without doing vaccum. Of course assuing the object is small compared with 1m.